# Remove columns from datatable

Tags: c#, linq

I have a datatable with 20 columns. But i don't need all the columns for the current processing except 5. So i did the below to remove the columns

```
List<string> clmnames = new List<string>() { "clm6","clm7"..."clm20" };
foreach (string dcName in clmnames)
{
  TestAndRemoveColumn(dcName, ds.Tables["TestTable"]);
}


 private void TestAndRemoveColumn(string dcName,DataTable datatable)
 {
       DataColumnCollection dcCollection = datatable.Columns;
       if (dcCollection.Contains(dcName))
       {
           dcCollection.Remove(dcName);
       }
 }
```

Instead of looping through the 15 times is there any other way to achieve using easily ?

Comment: Is there any rational reason you don't want to do it with an iteration? That looks pretty easy to me. =)

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just modify your query to not include those columns in the first place? Or maybe I should have asked how the DataTable is populated first?

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
List<string> listtoRemove = new List<string> { "CLM6", "CLM7", "CLM20" };
for (int i = dt.Columns.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
   DataColumn dc = dt.Columns[i];
   if (listtoRemove.Contains(dc.ColumnName.ToUpper()))
   {
       dt.Columns.Remove(dc);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In some scenarios may be preferable to clone DataTable and specify columns to copy.

```
DataView view = new DataView(table);
DataTable table2 = view.ToTable(false, "clm6", "clm7", ...);
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem seems to be in your code, you get all the comlumns from the datatable then remove the columns but you have not again assign the columns to that datatable
first you get columns

```
   DataColumnCollection dcCollection = datatable.Columns; // get cols
   if (dcCollection.Contains(dcName))
   {
       dcCollection.Remove(dcName); /// remove columns
     // but you have not updated you datatable columns.
        here should be something like this
       datatable.Columns = dcCollection; /// i don't know this will work or not check it
   }
```

Try this

```
 DataTable dt;
 dt.Columns.Remove("columnName");
 dt.Columns.RemoveAt(columnIndex);
```

you can use them as

```
private void TestAndRemoveColumn(string dcName,DataTable datatable)
{
    DataTable dt = datatable; 
    dt.Columns.Remove("dcName");      
}
```

Comment: To remove the all my 15 columns i need to write the above code 15 times.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can select only the required columns(Only 5 in your case) like this.

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("ID");
        dt.Columns.Add("Value");

        dt.Rows.Add("1", "One");
        dt.Rows.Add("2", "Two");

        string[] arr= new string[1];
        arr[0] = "Value";//add the required columns to the array
        
        //return only the required columns.
        DataTable dt2 = dt.DefaultView.ToTable(false, arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could join the columns you want remove with the available columns:

```
var keepColNames = new List<String>(){ "clm5" };
var allColumns   = tbl.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>();
var allColNames  = allColumns.Select(c => c.ColumnName);
var removeColNames = allColNames.Except(keepColNames);
var colsToRemove = from r in removeColNames
                   join c in allColumns on r equals c.ColumnName
                   select c;
while (colsToRemove.Any())
    tbl.Columns.Remove(colsToRemove.First());
```

If you know that you only have few remaining columns, you could add the column(s):

```
var colsToAdd = (from keepCol in keepColNames
                 join col in tbl.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                 on keepCol equals col.ColumnName
                 select col).ToList();
tbl.Columns.Clear();
foreach (var colToAdd in colsToAdd)
    tbl.Columns.Add(colToAdd);
```

Comment: Tim-Is this can be achieved without foreach statement ?

Comment: Loop is still there... I am not sure this is what he wants

Comment: @Pradeep: You can do the opposite if you know that there are only a few columns. `Clear` the columns first and add only these(see my edited answer). In general: of course it is **impossible** to remove or add columns without loops(implicit or explicit) since it could be multiple columns. So i assumed that this question asks for efficiency (readability, conciseness, performance).