# Removing columns from DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable

I am trying to delete datacolumns from a datatable: I get the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.'
```

when i try to execute the following code:

```
foreach (DataColumn col in csvData.Columns)
        {
            if (col.ColumnName.Contains("Column"))
            {
                csvData.Columns.Remove(col);
            }
        }
```

I do understand the error, since i is true that i am modifying the collection. I just don't know how to handle it. Anyone have an idea? I tried rapping it in a try/catch, but that only removes the first column containing *column*.

Comment: Put the columns to delete into a new collection and remove outside `foreach`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove columns from datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11667015/remove-columns-from-datatable)

Comment: @Pavel No, i know how to use google. This is one of the first answers that comes up. I have also tried to create a collection outside the foreach loop, then i get an error saying it can't remove columns not in the "original" collection

Comment: Inside a `foreach` you are not allowed to modify the collection you are currently enumerating (only its items). If you replace the enumerator based  `foreach` with an index based `for` loop your code won't throw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should solve the issue, by using a `for` loop and go from upperbound to `0`

```cs
for (int i = csvData.Columns.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
   DataColumn dc = csvData.Columns[i];
   if (dc.ColumnName.Contains("Column"))
   {
       csvData.Columns.Remove(dc);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i suppose this was what BionicCode meant. I will accept this as an aswer as soon as i can.